# Lambda with inner class implementing an interface

Tags: c++, c++11, interface, lambda, inner-classes

I am not very experienced with lambdas yet but I begin to like them very much and use them where it makes sense and where I feel they are the way to go.

Anyway, I have a class `Tree` that has a `Tree::Visitor` class with one virtual callback function called `visit(/*args*/)`. That Visitor class does a recursive walk over all nodes. With this callback I am able to collect data from each node (or better I can extract paths of the tree (which is basically what I do with this function).

So I take a lambda and inside I use a class to implement the `visit` callback function by deriving from `Tree::Visitor`.

```
// Tree class, a rough view how it looks
class Tree {

    // ...

    // Visitor class for recursive walking the tree
    class Visitor {
       // 
       void count(/* ... */) {
           // in here the implemented visit(/*args*/) fct is called
       }

       // ...
       void triggerVisit() { 
           // ...
           count(/* ... */);
           // ...
       }

       // visitor callback
       virtual void visit(/* args */) = 0;
    };
};

class A {
    Tree tree;
    PriorityQueue que;

    A() : tree(), que(maxEntries) {}

    // first build the tree ...
    void buildTheTree() {
        tree.buildTree();               
    }

    // walk the tree
    void visitTheTree() {

       std::shared_ptr<Tree::Visitor>(
          [&]()->Tree::Visitor * {

             // this class implements visit(/*args*/)
             class MyVisitor : public Tree::Visitor {
                 A& parent; // pointer to A

                 Myvisitor(A& p) 
                 : Tree::Visitor(p.tree), parent(p) {}      

                 // implementation
                 virtual void visit( /* args */ ) {

                     // ... get somedata 

                     if (/* condition true */) {
                         parent.que.push(somedata);
                     }
                 }  
             };

             return new MyVisitor(*this);

          }()
       )->triggerVisit();

       // get the collected data from que
       while(que.size() > 0) {
          // ...
       }
    }
};
```

Basically this is what I have and it is working without problems.

I have a priority queue `que` that I use to store `somedata`, that are the `n` top scored nodes of the tree. At this time that `que` is defined as a member of class `A`, which I dislike, because I just need to collect the data inside the visitTheTree member, so it could be rather a local variable
So my question is more a question of design/style and I have the feeling I miss something with the c++11 standard (maybe).

I tried to define `que` inside `visitTheTree()` and pass it with the constructor of `MyVisitor`. Somehow this is not working correctly, at least I do not get proper/complete results I expect. When I define the Priority queue variable as a member of A (as it is now) and access it with the parent pointer in MyVistor, I get proper results and all is fine.

Is there any good way to define `que` locally in VisitTheTree() instead of defining it in the class A as a member? I know I have to pass it with the constructor as I can not access variables outside the MyVistor (just like this).

BTW, I found the question [C++0x - lambda expression does look same as Java's anonymous inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163569/c0x-lambda-expression-does-look-same-as-javas-anonymous-inner-class) which comes close to the problem/question I have. Interesting is the answer from Johannes.

Any hints or ideas would be welcome. Thanks for your thoughts and help!

Comment: Is starting from scratch an option at all? I have the impression that a lot of the code you've outlined is not necessary -- I would go so far as to say that the interesting parts are in fact what you left out. Are you familiar with a fold (which usually takes the guise of `std::accumulate` in C++)? That may be an appropriate way to aggregate your result as you go over the data. Something else may be appropriate, but it depends how you go over the data, and what result you want. Those are the missing interesting bits.

Comment: @LucDanton I have never used std::accumulate, I think I can not use it in this case. Probably if I had a container (eg. vector of objects) I could go that way. I am happy with the overall design and do not think about a rewrite the tree, because it works well as is. I am just thinking on that part above that collects the data with the visitor, maybe there is no other way as it is now, I was just wondering if I could somehow relocate the `que` variable to a local variable inside `visitTheTree`, as I just need it there.

Comment: I did not recommend using `std::accumulate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andreas, I would really like to help you, but I cannot see a way to do it using your design. I had a similar situation using boost graph library, and I made the following (hope it helps you):

- Visitor has a `std::function<RET (/*args*/>` member that is used to make an action every node you visit. I would also make this function a parameter for the visitor constructor.
- Every time you need to visit some nodes you will make it through a new instance of your visitor passing a new lambda function as the argument.

I would try to provide some example,

```
class Tree {
    ...
    typedef std::function<void (/*node and args*/)> visit_fn;

    class Visitor {
        visit_fn& visitor;

        public:
            Visitor( visit_fn f ) : visitor( f ) {}
        ...
    };
};

class A {

    ...

    void visit_tree() {
        que.clear(); // could also be a local queue object

        Visitor vis([&](/*args*/) {
            que.push( some_data ); /*I have que because of & in my lambda*/
        });

        vis.triggerVisit();

        // Her I can use my queue member
    }

};
```

Now, if you have a commom way to visit your elements you can even pass a Functor to your Visitor, providing better code reuse.

I really think that the lambda in your design is not using the `[&]` binding, and in this sense could be a common function, wich I think would be more clean, reusable and efficient.

Comment: Julio, thanks for your post. I will consider your way, maybe I could go your direction. The `[&]` binding is for `this` inside the lambda, I also could use `[=]` here, I suppose.

Comment: One more, I just edited my code as I should mention, that there is a `count()` function that does some path/node counting works, the implemented `visit()` fct in the `Tree::Visitor` class gets called in `count()`. In the lambda enclosed class I do the implementation of it.

Comment: Yes, you could use the `[=]`, but I think the best way to answer your question is to remove the queue member variable of `class A`, and use a local queue just before calling the visitor (where I'm calling `que.clear()`). If you use a local queue, you can pass just it, as in `[&local_queue]`.

Comment: Julio, I tried your approach and it seems to work partially, but I can't get it fully to work. For some reason the `Tree` object gives me a problem with that way. So for now I have this: I defined the `PriorityQueue` as a member of `MyVisitor` and access it via a cast from outside, after the visiting of the tree is done. This also works, does not break my current implementation and for now it is OK for me. But anyway, I like that way you showed me and I wish I could it get to work, it really seems like a clean way. I will keep it in mind. I accepted your answer as I think it is OK!